# Python remove middle initial from then end of a name string

Tags: python, regex, pandas, string

I am trying to remove the middle initial at the end of a name string. An example of how the data looks:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Smith, Jake K',
                            'Howard, Rob',
                            'Smith-Howard, Emily R',
                            'McDonald, Jim T',
                            'McCormick, Erica']})
```

I am currently using the following code, which works for all names except for McCormick, Erica. I first use regex to identify all capital letters. Then any rows with 3 or more capital letters, I remove [:-1] from the string (in an attempt to remove the middle initial and extra space).

```
df['Cap_Letters'] = df['Name'].str.findall(r'[A-Z]')
df.loc[df['Cap_Letters'].str.len() >= 3, 'Name'] = df['Name'].str[:-1]
```

This outputs the following:

[image]

As you can see, this properly removes the middle initial for all names except for McCormick, Erica. Reason being she has 3 capital letters but no middle initial, which incorrectly removes the 'a' in Erica.

Comment: If all middle initials are the last word in the string and set off by spaces, have you tried string's `split` method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Series.str.replace` directly:

```py
df['Name'] = df['Name'].str.replace(r'\s+[A-Z]$', '', regex=True)
```

Output:

```
0            Smith, Jake
1            Howard, Rob
2    Smith-Howard, Emily
3          McDonald, Jim
4       McCormick, Erica
Name: Name, dtype: object
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/S0zHRX/1). *Regex details*:

- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `[A-Z]` - an uppercase letter
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution(not so pretty) would be to split then take 2 elements then join again

```py
df['Name'] = df['Name'].str.split().str[0:2].str.join(' ')

# 0            Smith, Jake
# 1            Howard, Rob
# 2    Smith-Howard, Emily
# 3          McDonald, Jim
# 4       McCormick, Erica
# Name: Name, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use something like that :

```
def removeMaj(string):
   tab=string.split(',')
   tab[1]=lower(tab[1])
   string=",".join(tab)
   return(string)
```